when examining the distinction between tribble and data.frame i cam across the rounding issue
Take a look at the provided data and observe the result: the output from tribble is rounding the value to the nearest integer, whereas data.frame does not.
Is there a method we can employ to prevent rounding when constructing the data frame using tribble?

I tried as.double but it does not solve the issue
tribble <- tribble(
   ~Price,
  as.double(899.30),
  as.double(699.99),
  )


Please note that the data is not rounded. The display/print depends on the tibble options of your setup. ie try storing the data in a variable and call the varible eg df$Price, and you will not that the data is stored correctly

Also, I know this is just an example, but I would avoid using tribble and data.frame as object names.

Try running this code old <- options(pillar.sigfig = 5); tribble; options(old). old is just capturing your previous options and resetting them at the end, FYI.
